# Remove right half of string after a certain number of spaces

Tags: string, excel, vba

I'm writing a macro in Excel that is reading some text from a single cell.

```
ProductID = rw.Cells(1, 1).Text
```

However the cell may contain some buffer characters, specifically 5 consecutive space characters. I am trying to remove all the characters (length and actual text may vary) after the 5 spaces (including the spaces).

So if the string was:

```
MyProduct123     removethis
```

The desired string would be

```
MyProduct123
```

It seems I can remove the 5 spaces with

```
Replace(MyProductStr, "     ", "")
```

but how can I get the position of the right side string or the text to remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to find the starting position of the five spaces, and then [Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y050k1wb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to take just the part of the string before that:

```
Dim pos As Integer

pos = InStr(ProductID, "     ")

If pos > 0 Then
   ProductID = Left(ProductID, pos - 1)
End If
```

Comment: Yup that did the trick thanks. Used `pos - 1` to remove an extra space at the end.